# Reading semicolon separated data with read_html

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read [`winequality-white.csv`](https://github.com/shrikant-temburwar/Wine-Quality-Dataset/blob/master/winequality-white.csv) data using `pandas.read_html()` function.

Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd

wine = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.read_html(
        "https://github.com/shrikant-temburwar/Wine-Quality-Dataset/blob/master/winequality-white.csv",
        thousands=";",
        header=0,
    )[0]
)
```

... but the result is:

```py
Unnamed: 0 "fixed acidity";"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"residual sugar";"chlorides";"free sulfur dioxide";"total sulfur dioxide";"density";"pH";"sulphates";"alcohol";"quality"
    0         NaN   7;0.27;0.36;20.7;0.045;45;170;1.001;3;0.45;8.8;6                                                                                                                       
    1         NaN  6.3;0.3;0.34;1.6;0.049;14;132;0.994;3.3;0.49;9...                                                                                                                       
    2         NaN  8.1;0.28;0.4;6.9;0.05;30;97;0.9951;3.26;0.44;1...                                                                                                                       
    3         NaN  7.2;0.23;0.32;8.5;0.058;47;186;0.9956;3.19;0.4...                                                                                                                       
    4         NaN  7.2;0.23;0.32;8.5;0.058;47;186;0.9956;3.19;0.4...
```

Of course I can choose `raw` and then use `read_csv`, but in case of `html` reading, how can I fix it?

Comment: But why oh why read it with `pd.read_html()`?! Also, `pd.DataFrame(pd.read_html(` is redundant since `pd.read_html()` returns a `pd.DataFrame()` already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, here is an option using `pd.read_html`:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://github.com/shrikant-temburwar/Wine-Quality-Dataset/blob/master/winequality-white.csv'

wine = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]

wine.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
headers = wine.columns[0].replace('"', '').split(';')
wine.columns = ['data']
wine[headers] = wine.data.str.split(';', expand=True)
wine.drop('data', axis=1, inplace=True)
wine.head()
```

The code above will result in:

```
>>> wine.head()
  fixed acidity volatile acidity citric acid residual sugar chlorides free sulfur dioxide total sulfur dioxide density    pH sulphates alcohol quality
0             7             0.27        0.36           20.7     0.045                  45                  170   1.001     3      0.45     8.8       6
1           6.3              0.3        0.34            1.6     0.049                  14                  132   0.994   3.3      0.49     9.5       6
2           8.1             0.28         0.4            6.9      0.05                  30                   97  0.9951  3.26      0.44    10.1       6
3           7.2             0.23        0.32            8.5     0.058                  47                  186  0.9956  3.19       0.4     9.9       6
4           7.2             0.23        0.32            8.5     0.058                  47                  186  0.9956  3.19       0.4     9.9       6
>>>
```

But I would never exchange the simplicity of the following snippet for the above code:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shrikant-temburwar/Wine-Quality-Dataset/master/winequality-white.csv'

wine = pd.read_csv(url, header=0, sep=';')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could probably better to use the rawdatacontent address of github to remove the problem due to different html interface.

here is what you could do

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shrikant-temburwar/Wine-Quality-Dataset/master/winequality-white.csv"
r = requests.get(url)
obj = io.BytesIO(r.content)
wine = pd.read_csv(obj, delimiter=";")
wine.head()
```

Comment: OP is aware of `pd.read_csv()` and explicitly said they want an option using `pd.read_html()`. Also, you are over-complicating it by adding `io.BytesIO()` and `requests` to the mix. Both `pd.read_html()` and `pd.read_csv()` are capable to handle `URL` by themselves.

Comment: I did not see the comment below that they are aware of raw content. and first reading file then parsing by read_csv, I consider it safer than directly giving a path to online content. thanks for your feedback